# How to embed my own Google Maps Data Layer (with my custom marker)s and enable API interactions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-storage, geojson

I'm currently working on a web project and could use some guidance. I'm in the process of integrating a Google Maps Data Layer into my web app. My main goal is to interact with the geographic data and custom markers - Interact with the map using APIs.

I'm using GeoJSON for my data format, but I'm open to any suggestions you might have. Perhaps you could share some code examples to help me bring this project to life?

Progress So Far:
I've successfully embedded the Google Maps Data Layer with custom markers(not in the code i added here). However, when it comes to interacting with the data using JavaScript, I've encountered challenges. Specifically, I've faced difficulties in fetching and using GeoJSON data. I want a way to interact with my map layer like i can interact with google maps's base map.
**i want to "ask" for the nearest locations from my marked locations map, and navigate to them, both on the map itself and on google maps**. i will add photos of something that work but with google maps's map
[image that shows the "navigate" future avalible on the "normal" google maps map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgYSP.jpg)

Part of my GeoJSON:

"markers": [
{
"type": "Marker",
"properties": {
"name": "Place A",
"description": "Description of Place A",
"icon": "https://example.com/icon1.png"
},
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [-122.41669, 37.7853]
}
},
// More markers
]

I'm seeking guidance and potential solutions

A Peek at My Code(not currently working):

```js
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 20, lng: -160 },
    zoom: 2,
  });

  // Get the earthquake data (JSONP format)
  // This feed is a copy from the USGS feed, you can find the originals here:
  //   http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php
  const script = document.createElement("script");

  script.setAttribute(
    "src",
    "gs://firstbucketfor2locationsmapslaer/גאו.geojson",
  );
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}

// Defines the callback function referenced in the jsonp file.
function eqfeed_callback(data) {
  map.data.addGeoJson(data);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
window.eqfeed_callback = eqfeed_callback;let map;
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: aliceblue;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#map {
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>map layer</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="themlayer.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>my map layer</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="scriptlayerv1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyApiKey&map_ids=mapId&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you mean like a feature listener to your layers? Like this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/dds-boundaries/handle-events

Comment: Hello and thank you for your suggestion! However, I am looking for a solution that allows me to interact with my custom map layer using built-in functions like service.nearbySearch(), similar to the standard Google Maps js API. My aim is to replicate the functionality available on the normal map for mine.
If you have any insights or examples specifically related to using these functions with a custom map layer, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide example GeoJSON.  What kind of data does it contain? Only markers?  Polylines, Polygons?

Comment: My GeoJSON file contains markers representing different locations.
 - I edited and added to my QA part of my GeoJSON.